# Get identity of transaction submitter in Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

In Hyperledger Fabric, it is possible to return the history of changes on a state entry by calling the chain code API [getHistoryForKey](https://fabric-shim.github.io/ChaincodeStub.html#getHistoryForKey__anchor).

This returns json data more or less like below...

From this, how can I determine which `user` submitted this transaction ?

```
{ 
  TxId: '07d8b9107d27a6fe75456f688543d7985b15bc92b10c37744ff8f4bde6627bc0',
  Timestamp: { seconds: [Object], nanos: 714000000 },
  IsDelete: 'false',
  Value: { myDataBlahBlahBlah: true } 
}
```

I'm using the node implementation of chain code (if that makes any difference to the answer).

Answer (score 0):

The cid package is available for this purpose:
 github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim/ext/cid

Comment: Is there an API to get transaction details by transaction key?

Comment: Chiancode [shim](https://godoc.org/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim) package does not have any such API. But, yes all SDKs( node js, Java) have one such API :queryTransactionByID. This API utilizes system chaincode 'qscc' and a function: GetTransactionByID defined in this chaincode. [Here](https://github.com/vishal3152/HyperledgerFabric-Java-Client/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fabric/client/ChannelWrapper.java) is how one example on how to use this API.